# Select in parenthesis is not null

Tags: mysql

I'm not quite sure how to do this:

```
SELECT contacts.first_name,
       contacts.last_name,
       (
            SELECT quotes.id
            FROM quotes 
            LEFT JOIN quotes_contacts ON quotes.id = quotes_contacts.quote_id
            WHERE quotes.id IS NOT NULL
            AND quotes_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id
            ORDER BY quotes.date_entered
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'first_quote'
FROM
contacts
```

But some of the values returned as `first_quote` are being returned as `null`. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a subselect, use an `INNER JOIN` against the subquery. That will eliminate the NULLs.

```
SELECT contacts.first_name,
       contacts.last_name,
       quote_id AS first_quote
FROM 
  contacts 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT quotes.id, quotes_contacts.contact_id
    FROM 
     quotes 
     LEFT JOIN quotes_contacts ON quotes.id = quotes_contacts.quote_id
     JOIN (
       SELECT quotes_contacts.contact_id, MIN(quotes.date_entered) AS date_entered
       FROM 
             quotes 
         JOIN quotes_contacts ON quotes.id = quotes_contacts.quote_id
         GROUP BY contact_id
     ) minquote ON quotes.date_entered = minquote.date_entered AND qc.contact_id = minquote.contact_id
   ) firstquote ON contacts.id = firstquote.contact_id
```

This can be simpler if you are *certain* that the `quote.id` is incrementing, and the lowest `quote.id` per `contact_id` also has the earliest `date_entered`. In that case you can just do a `MIN(quote.id)`

```
SELECT contacts.first_name,
       contacts.last_name,
       quote_id AS first_quote
FROM 
  contacts 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(quotes.id) AS quote_id, quotes_contacts.contact_id
    FROM quotes
    LEFT JOIN  quotes_contacts ON quotes.id = quotes_contacts.quote_id
    GROUP BY contact_id
  )minq ON contacts.id = minq.contact_id
```

Comment: Awesome that sound like what I need. Although I'm getting this: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS first_quote  FROM  contacts  INNER JOIN (  SELECT quotes . id , contact_id  F' at line 1`

Comment: Missing `,` after `contacts.last_name`

Comment: A couple of other alias changes edited above, and an unnecessary component removed from the inner ON clause...

Comment: It works, but it just returns all of the quotes associated with a contact. There's a contact with the id `8a3b3aff` and because he has 5 quotes, he appears 5 times. I just need the first created quote from that user.

Comment: @andy You still have the order by and limit in the subquery? Run the subquery by itself and verify you get one quote per contact

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just get back 1 record

Comment: There - more complicated but will probably work unless it has a syntax problem. A double nested subquery join gets the earliest quote per contact id

Comment: Awesome great thank you it works :) Sorry to be a pain I've been trying to figure this out for ages haha

Comment: @andy No problem - I should have caught my mistake right away after copy/pasting from the original subselect.

Answer (score 0):

If the subselect finds a row and the value of `id` is null, your `WHERE` clause prevents it from being returned.  But whenever the subselect doesn't find anything at all, the value of `first_quote` will still be null.  An extra guard on the outside should do the trick:

```
SELECT contacts.first_name,
       contacts.last_name,
       (
            SELECT quotes.id
              FROM quotes 
              LEFT JOIN quotes_contacts ON quotes.id = quotes_contacts.quote_id
             WHERE quotes.id IS NOT NULL
               AND quotes_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id
             ORDER BY quotes.date_entered
             LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'first_quote'
 FROM contacts
WHERE first_quote IS NOT NULL
```

But a JOIN would be more efficient than a subselect here.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that way but it produces `#1054 - Unknown column 'first_quote' in 'where clause'`